# JS input field result to show 2 decimal placings

Tags: javascript, calculator

I've seen a lot of posts about this sort of topic, but I can't find any specifics to add into my relatively simple JS to get numerical results to appear to 2 decimal places - the answer is probably so simple, but somehow I can't figure it out.

It is for a calculator, you write two entries into 2 fields, and the 3rd returns the multiplied answer of the 2 numbers - fine.

However, if the number is not whole, and requires decimal placings, it shows the full string, not the 2 decimal place answer which is imperative.

```
function calculate() {
    var no1 = document.getElementById('number1').value; 
    var no2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = no1 * no2;
    result.value = myResult;
        }
```

A simpler fix the better, as I imagine for every entry like that ^, I'd have to make an amendment and right now the code entries are close to 1000 as its a bet calculator with full manual input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Number.prototype.toFixed` method:

```
function calculate() {
    var no1 = document.getElementById('number1').value; 
    var no2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = (no1 * no2);
    myResult = myResult % 1 ? myResult.toFixed(2) : myResult;
    result.value = myResult;
}
```

Comment: Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer whenever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Add following condition, if you only want to show 2 decimal places if the number has decimal otherwise you want to keep it as it is i.e. as a whole number:

```
if( Number(myResult) === parseInt(myResult) ){
  myResult = myResul.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: should be .toFixed(2)